# Export big Excel with Laravel Excel 3.1

Tags: php, excel, laravel

Hello I need help with Laravel Excel 3.1 with Laravel 7.

I have to export an excel with arround 300,000 records o more and download or save in public folder to download...

So when i do it with this plugin, localhost works fine. But in the server it shows an error 500.
I set memory limit = -1 and time execution = 1800.

it takes time to appear error 500 arround 10min or less.

This is my code:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;

class ProductsExport implements FromQuery
    {
        protected $filters;
       
        use Exportable;
        function __construct($filters) {
               $this->filters= $filters;       
        }
        public function query()
        {
            return Product::query()
            ->where($this->filters)        
            ->orderby('name');
         
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
(new ProductsExport($filters)->queue('products.xlsx');
   return back()->withSuccess('Export started!');
```

In excel.php I just configured chunk_size to 5000. I don't know what else I need to configure here

I know that i need to use queue for big data, and i used it, but i dont know what else to do.

Comment: Try using `DB` instead of models directly as that class has less overhead, also might be worth explicitly stating which columns you need from the table.

Comment: @thursday_dan I made the change but still the same. Columns are only six.